# EndSave (AutoCAD) is member of what (.net vb)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad, addhandler

`EndSave` (AutoCAD) is member of what (.net vb)?

Is it `Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument`?

I don't know where it is, so I can add a handler to register its event.

Comment: it doesn't exist so you have to add your own handling.

Comment: I [Googled "EndSave AutoCAD"](https://www.google.com/search?q=EndSave+AutoCAD) and [How to handle the EndSave event (.net vb)?](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/how-to-handle-the-endsave-event-net-vb/td-p/8252214) was one of the first results.  It would be helpful to potential respondents if your StackOverflow question contained as much detail and description as your AutoDesk forums question since the title, if not the body, takes a few reads to figure out what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dediced to use the CommandEnded Event instead of the `DocumentLockModeChanged`. Now it only register if the save commands (QSAVe, SAVE, SAVEAS) have been ended.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to delcare the imports:

```
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput
Imports System.Windows
```

**1)** handle he `DocumentLockModeChanged` event like this:

```
Public Sub Initialize() Implements Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.IExtensionApplication.Initialize
    Try
        subHandler = New DocumentLockModeChangedEventHandler(AddressOf docChange)
        AddHandler Application.DocumentManager.DocumentLockModeChanged, subHandler
    Catch ex As Exception
        Err.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**2)** and then check if the `command` is *SAVE* or *SAVEAS*:

```
Implements Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.IExtensionApplication
Dim subHandler As [Delegate]
Public Sub docChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DocumentLockModeChangedEventArgs)
    If e.GlobalCommandName = "QSAVE" Or e.GlobalCommandName = "SAVE" Or e.GlobalCommandName = "SAVEAS" Then   
        Application.ShowAlertDialog("Save has occurred")
    End If
End Sub
```

At this point if you want, you can add the handle for the *terminate* event, like this:

```
Public Sub Terminate() Implements Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.IExtensionApplication.Terminate
    RemoveHandler Application.DocumentManager.DocumentLockModeChanged, subHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that page already. That is for the DocumentDestroyed Event. I'm looking for the EndSave Event. I don't know what is the delegate for the EndSave Event. What is it?

Comment: I found the answer but currently I'm having lunch, give me a few minutes ;)

Comment: Hi @Simo.

I have insert it inside a class. Now it says:

Interface 'IExtensionApplication' is not implemented by this class

What does this mean?

And then subHandler and docChange are not declared.

Comment: @RitaAguiar sorry but StackOverflow is not a place where someone else codes programs for you. Is a place where someone helps you. Now is up to you to read the documentation about AutoCad, in a more specific way the documentation related to `IExtensionApplication`.

This is another [example](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-FA3B4125-F7BD-4E89-969F-9DCC90AC6977-htm.html) of how to implements `IExtensionApplication`

Comment: I managed to implement this, however it will register when the user executes the save commands and before he finishes them. If the user cancels the save, it has already register as if he did save the drawing.

Comment: I dediced to use the CommandEnded Event instead of the DocumentLockModeChanged
Now it only register if the save commands have been ended.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue, but is the best option possible

Comment: @RitaAguiar edit your post to add your solution, or add an answer